# Angular-UI Modal won't open until resolve promises are fulfilled?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-promise

This is my code:

```
var defObj = $q.defer(),
    data = defObj.promise;

$modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'modal-base.html',
            controller: 'modalCtrl',
            scope: scope,
            size: size || "sm",
            resolve: {
                data: function(){
                    return data;
                }
            }
        })

$timeout(function () {
    defObj.resolve({foo: "bar"});
}, 5000);
```

What I noticed is that the modal won't open until data promise is fulfilled. Is that right?
Is possible to bypass this and manage the promise inside the modal controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the point of the resolve is that it will pre-load the data.  If you want the data to load after the view then you can load the data directly inside the controller.  You simply remove the resolve.